# Is there a way in facebook to send a link to a user's friends and allow them to choose the friends they want to receive it?

Tags: facebook

We currently have a system in place to allow affiliates and existing users to refer business to our website.  We use a special parameter to track record who referred the user.

I now have a requirement to allow the user to refer the site to his facebook friends and allow him to choose the recipients.  The app request dialog sort of gives me what I want but from what I can tell, it has a several problems.  One is that the app seems to need to be a canvas app in order to show up in the user's list of apps.  The notification appears, but the app does not.  The second problem is that if it is a canvas app, facebook posts to the canvas URL which requires me to create a special page to handle this.  The biggest problem I have found so far is that I will have to maintain the request ids and their mapping back to the requesting user.  I also have the requirement to do this sort of thing via twitter, etc. and I need to do this in a social media-agnostic way.

Similarly, the send dialog sort of does what I want, but it doesn't have the same mechanism to choose the friends to whom he wishes to send the link.

Overall, the send dialog is seems to be more of what I need, but I don't know how to make it present the user with a list of friends.  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the Send button/dialog and let the user choose their own friends? you've already added an incentive for them, surely they'll choose as many friends as they can?

Comment: The problem with the send dialog is that it doesn't allow the user to choose friends in the same way that app request does.  Instead, you enter people as you would in the "to" field of an email.  If I am wrong on that point, please correct me.

Comment: No, that's the way it works, but there isn't a dialog which supports choosing friends from a list except the Requests dialog, and this is only used for sending app requests - which will bring the user back to your canvas app and require more logic from your side to process the requests